# Spring - Websockets - JSR-356

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster, spring-websocket

I implemented websockets into my application. I copied the configuration and dependencies from jHipster generated app, but I am getting the following errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' ServletContext attribute. Are you running in a Servlet container that supports JSR-356?
```

and

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

I believe these errors are the reason for the socket connection not being consistent and the therefore the client is not able to send and/or receive any messages.
I searched for a solution but other post didn't help (ie. adding glassfish dependencies).

These are my ws dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Do I need to include some other dependencies or is the problem elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/15467?focusedCommentId=92892&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-92892).
I added these 2 beans:

```
    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatContainerFactory() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();;
        factory.setTomcatContextCustomizers(Collections.singletonList(tomcatContextCustomizer()));
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public TomcatContextCustomizer tomcatContextCustomizer() {
        return new TomcatContextCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Context context) {
                context.addServletContainerInitializer(new WsSci(), null);
            }
        };
    }
```